# Transfer of wordpress site from one domain and server to another domain and server

Tags: domain, migration

I have moved a wordpress site from one domain and server to another domain and server. Everything looks fine except all the links within the site are still pointing to the previous domain. Please let me know what went wrong with the transfer. I'll really be thankful for the kind response and help.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, nothing went wrong, you just have to set some things to the new server.

Firstly, there are the home and site urls (to be found in the general settings).

Then, possible absolute links pointing to the *old* domain have to be adapted.

To change these links, you have to adapt the SQL table.

Update options (this can also be done via the general settings, as described above):

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://old-domain.com', 'http://new-domain.com')
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Update absolute links inside posts:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://old-domain.com', 'http://new-domain.com');
```

Comment: +1 though I would recommend [Velvet Blues Update URLs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to sort out the absolute links.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that plugin, though I was sure there **is** one for this particular task. Thanks.

Comment: I am not affiliated at all with that plugin but it is one of the very, very few I use, much less recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to log into the admin portal (www.yoursite.com/wp-admin) and change the site's address under settings >> general >> wordpress address.

Hope that helps