# How to completely save my wordpress data?

Tags: backup

I am changing domain and I was wondering if using the export tool on my wordpress admin panel was enough to save all of my wordpress data? What I want to do is intall a new version of wordpress on my new domain and import the file I have exported using the tools. Does that file contain everything? Members, posts, images, preferences, etc? What does it save exactly. I want my other site to be exactly the same (I know I will have to add the theme again)

Comment: Codex has good documentation on this process: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), [Backing up your database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export tools build in Wordpress can export only content: posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus and custom posts. It dosen't export settings, preferences or users. So, in your case, as you want your new installation be exactly the same, it is better to export your entire database using a different tool, for example PHP MyAdmin. This is the way I move Wordpress through differents domains with success:

1. Make a backup of the entire database of your site and import it in the database for the new domain. This process is not done by the export/import tool in Wordpress, instead you have to do it through the database manager of your server, for example I use PHP MyAdmin.
2. Transfer your theme, wp-uploads and plugins folders to your new site.
3. Transfer the wp-config.php file from the old to the new site. Edit this file with the access data to the new database (database name, database user and password)
4. Finally, use the [Search & Replace for Wordpress database](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to find all references to your old domain in the database and replace them with your new domain.
5. Check everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

To **save your *content data***, it is sufficient to **do an export** via the admin panel. Of course, you could also export the SQL tables *by hand*.

In addition, you might want to **save all your files**, meaning via FTP.

And after having imported your data into your new WP install, you have to [**adapt some database settings**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92297/transfer-of-wordpress-site-from-one-domain-and-server-to-another-domain-and-serv/92301#92301).